# Devexpress how to get clicked point in SwiftPlotSeriesView?

Tags: charts, onclick, devexpress

I'm using DEvexpress XtraCharts fro winforms and i wonder how i can get the clicked series point?
My code is

```
 private void chart_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ChartHitInfo hi = chart.CalcHitInfo(e.X, e.Y);
            SeriesPoint point = hi.SeriesPoint;

            if (point != null)
            { // do stuff
}
}
```

Declaration:

```
chart.Series.Add(new Series() { Name = "Max" + channelName, LegendText = "Max",
```

View = new DevExpress.XtraCharts.SwiftPlotSeriesView()});

The point is always null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible, found this in devexpress support :The Swift plot chart does not render individual points: all points are connected in a line. Please note that the runtime Series hit-testing feature is disabled for the Swift plot because it requires a lot of extra calculations.